# Find mounted volumes and mountpoint of USB hard drives

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, usb

I am trying to write a Python script to identify USB devices that did not get auto-mounted correctly in Linux. I am currently using `subprocess` and calling lsusb to gather the USB devices and then using PyUsb (A libusb 1.0 python wrap library) to find the category of the USB device so I can identify if it is a Mass Storage Media. What I can't figure out is how to bridge the information I have  into the mountpoint that belongs to that USB drive. I need a combination of Linux commands that will get me the information I can use to link a mountpoint to a specific USB device so I can use `subprocess` and some basic parsing to create the script. Or maybe some other way to do this with Python modules I haven't thought of using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do it using information from `mount` and `fdisk`. I wrote a python module that encapsulates everything if anyone has the need for something similar: https://github.com/arthurbayerlein/Python/blob/master/storage_media.py